# UK equivalent of "stateside"

Tags: single-word-requests, british-english

The term stateside means "in the United States", is there an equivalent  word for the UK, or any other country?

Some examples might be: "It feels weird being stateside again." or "I'll be stateside next week."

I imagine it could be kingdomside or even queenside, but I've never heard anything like that.

Comment: I suspect every country has some nicknames.

Comment: Thesaurus.com gives several nicknames for the UK including Blighty and Albion, as well as some I've seldom or never heard (Limeyland, land of the rose). Blighty seems a little old fashioned but still current especially among older expatriates; Albion is more poetic (like Erin or Caledonia). As for other countries, Australia seems well equipped (Down Under, Oz), but as lbf says, I'm sure there are expressions for most countries if not all.

Comment: Do you want the word "side" to be in the nickname? Because many nicknames exist for regions of the world. Like the previous comment, 'down under'.

Comment: Surely the "equivalent" word on ***both*** sides of the pond is [***cisatlantic***](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/cisatlantic) *- on the same side of the Atlantic as the speaker*.

Comment: Nobody says "Albion". believe me.

Comment: I've heard in several British TV programs and movies the term "on the estate" used like "stateside," "estate" apparently referring to Britain herself. Maybe it's actually "Estate" (with a capital E) in that context. I don't know. So, instead of saying, "It feels weird being stateside again," you might hear, "It feels weird to be back on the Estate." One warning, though, it's possible that "Estate" doesn't refer to all of the UK but either to just the Isle of Great Britain or even to maybe just England but not Wales or Scotland on the Isle of Great Britain.

Comment: A thing I've heard Londoners say is "home counties." So, instead of saying, for example, "I'm heading back stateside," a Londoner abroad might say, "I'm heading back to the home counties."

Comment: I venture to think that British people are perhaps slightly less inclined to divide the world into two parts, namely "our homeland" and "the rest of the world", and thus, have less need of a word for the first of these. (Yes, I know about Brexit).

Answer (score 4):

The nearest equivalent for the UK is probably [Blighty](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/blighty). This is defined by Lexico as

> An informal term for Britain or England, used by soldiers of the First and Second World Wars.

The origin is thought to be the Urdu word bilāyatī meaning 'foreign' or 'european'

"Blighty" is used much less frequently than it used to be, it was most common in the first half of the last century, mainly n the military and is used in the phrase "in Blighty" as in "When I'm back in Blighty" or [in a 1950s folk song](http://www.traditionalmusic.co.uk/folk-song-lyrics/Shores_of_Old_Blighty.htm) "The shores of Old Blighty" - or the more cheerful ["They say there's a troopship just leaving Bombay, Bound for Old Blighty's shores...Bless 'em all, Bless 'em all..."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BYGyAez5_MI)

An interesting other use was the term "a Blighty one" which meant, in the trenches of WW1, an injury which was severe enough to need repatriation of the soldier but might not be severe enough to disable him permanently.

Comment: In the US, we used to call that type of injury a "million dollar wound".